# sqoop "import-all-tables" to Hive issue

Tags: sqoop

No errors displayed but at the end, out of 6 tables only 3 gets imported. Below is the snippet of last few lines of the results:

```
    Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-common-1.1.0-cdh5.8.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
    OK
    Time taken: 0.136 seconds
    Loading data to table default.departments
    chgrp: changing ownership of 'hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/**departments**/part-m-00000.snappy': User does not belong to supergroup
    Table default.departments stats: [numFiles=1, numRows=0, totalSize=70, rawDataSize=0]
    OK
    Time taken: 0.604 seconds
    Note: /tmp/sqoop-cloudera/compile/f85a6558ac82e6d24d3f3f6a57de1c3a/**order_items.**java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. [cloudera@quickstart ~]$
```

- In the above result, table "departments" got imported fine, but "order_items" did not.
- Got few hits for the answers here, but none of them ended with a resolution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: please share sqoop import query

Comment: Hi dev - here's the query:
  [cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sqoop import-all-tables \
  > --num-mappers 1 \
  > --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" \
  > --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \
  > --username retail_dba \
  > --hive-import \
  > --hive-overwrite \
  > --create-hive-table

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it is not logged on console.

In importing this table there could be exception like

> Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Hive does not support the SQL type for column `<somecolumn>`

For example, `varbinary` is not supported.

---

**What you can do?**

- Check data types for `order_items` table or
- Try importing only `order_items` table.

  ```
  sqoop import \
   --num-mappers 1 \
   --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" \
   --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \
   --username retail_dba \
   --password ****** \
   --table order_items \
   --hive-import \
   --hive-overwrite \
   --create-hive-table
  ```

Comment: I didn't get any exceptions while doing import-all-tables. I am able to import just the order_items table without any issues, using the above query. Guess some other issue with the import-all-table for hive.

Comment: @VijayU what are the datatypes in `order_items` table?

Comment: order_item_id                 | int(11) order_item_order_id       | int(11)   
order_item_product_id   | int(11)   
order_item_quantity       | tinyint(4)
order_item_subtotal       | float     
order_item_product_price | float

Comment: @VijayU datatypes are supported by sqoop. Only option left is to check yarn logs

Comment: The import query output log does not show any errors (shared the output initially). Is yarn log something different? How can I access it?
Thanks dev for looking into the issue!